# Meaning of "Borne to uphold Creation" in "The Two Noble Kinsmen"?

Tags: meaning, william-shakespeare

In [act I, scene 1](https://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/doc/TNK_Q1/scene/1.1/index.html), of *The Two Noble Kinsmen*, the second queen says:

> *2. Qu.*                             Honoured Hypolita
> Most dreaded Amazonian, that ha'st slaine
> The Sith-tuskd-Bore; that with thy Arme as strong
> As it is white, wast neere to make the male
> To thy Sex captive; but that this thy Lord
> **Borne to uphold Creation**, in that honour
> First nature stilde it in, shrunke thee into
> The bownd thou wast ore-flowing; at once subduing
> Thy force, and thy affection: Soldiresse
> That equally canst poize sternenes with pitty,
> Whom now I know hast much more power on him
> Then ever he had on thee, who ow'st his strength,
> And his, Love too: who is a Servant for
> The Tenour of the Speech.

[What might be meant](https://www.shakespeareswords.com/Public/Play.aspx?WorkId=37) here in the queen's words on Theseus, "Borne to [uphold](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uphold#Verb) Creation"? Is the queen saying that Theseus was born to assist other people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Creation” here means “the order of creation”, referring to the idea that because Adam was created before Eve in [Genesis 2](https://biblehub.com/genesis/2.htm), therefore men are superior to women. This is a common interpretation of a passage from the letters of Paul:

> I do not permit a woman to teach or to assume authority over a man; she must be quiet. For Adam was formed first, then Eve.
>
> <sub>[1 Timothy 2:12–13](https://biblehub.com/1_timothy/2.htm). New International Version.</sub>

Hippolyta was queen of the Amazons, a people in which the women ruled over the men (according to [Diodorus of Sicily](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.183639/page/33/mode/2up), “they mutilated both the legs and the arms of the male [children], incapacitating them in this way for the demands of war”), but she was abducted and wedded by Theseus, thus (in this view) restoring the superiority of men over women which was established at the creation. Hence Theseus was “born to uphold [the order of] creation”.

In the speech from *The Two Noble Kinsmen*, Hippolyta’s former warlike prowess, “near to make the male to [her] sex captive” is contrasted with her marital subjugation, “shrunk into the bound … subduing [her] force and [her] affection”.